# How can I Count, Compare and Add Values in DataGridView`s Rows?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

What do I need in order to be able to Count, Compare and Add values from DataGridView?

This is my line of code for inserting/populating my Datagridview

```
Sub display()
    Dim temp As Double = 0
    'count is my ID that counts the number of tickets from 1 and so on - count is also primary key in my database..
    Dim lt As String = "select count as Tickets, mname as Movie, mtime as Time, mprice as Price, mimg as Photo from tickets order by count asc" 'add desc for descending order/ asc for ascending (order by vlanme desc)
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(lt, con)
    con.Open()

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "settings")
    da.Dispose()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

What I want is to count how many rows my Datagridview has

I also want to compare Values between two Rows

I also want to add Values of the two Rows

I just want to count how many tickets do I have, compare Names of Row(1) and Row(2) and so on and Add the Prices from Row(1) and so on as a total

(I want to do this while not using the .SelectedCell Method because I will count, compare, add them all at once - all the existing data in datagridview)

Thank You!

Comment: I love those homeworks :-) I think, it is easier for you to read, if you use a DataTable instead a DataSet. For using the table, please take a look at the methods, the DataTable is giving you. To answer only one question (the rest is still your homework): DataTable.Rows.Count will return you the number of rows.

Comment: Thanks Sir Ill go and start reading about DataTable and DataSet

Comment: I cant seem to transfer my Values from DataGridView to my DataTable any suggestions Sir?

Comment: You want to edit your DGV like a grid in Excel? Or do you want to do something with your data BEFORE populating the DGV?

Comment: I want to do something with my data either BEFORE i populate or AFTER i populate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to this already

```
Dim bs As New BindingSource
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    Dim rowcount As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count
    Dim moviecount As Integer = 0
    Dim price As Integer = 0
    For index As Integer = 0 To rowcount
        Try
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                con.Open()
                Dim query As String = "select * from tickets where count = '" & index & "'"
                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
                While dr.Read
                    If moviecount = 0 Then
                        movie = dr.GetString("mname")
                        moviecount += 1
                    End If

                    If moviecount > 0 Then
                        If movie = dr.GetString("mname") Then
                            price += dr.GetInt32("mprice")
                        Else
                            MsgBox(movie & " has a total sales of : " & price, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "System Checked!")
                            price = 0
                            price += dr.GetInt32("mprice")
                            moviecount = 0
                        End If
                    End If
                End While
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        con.Close()
    Next
    MsgBox(movie & " has a total sales of : " & price, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "System Checked!")
```

dr.getString(" variable from database ") or dr.getInt32(" variable from database ")

this lets you choose which Value from database will be transferred to what ever Varname that you set to String or Int (also which row do you want if you add the loop)